# How to close a HttpWebResponse being returned from a method call

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse, idisposable, using

I have a helper class with a method that is set up to take in information to make a `HttpWebRequest`. The method as it currently is, returns a `HttpWebResponse`.

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
//make request here
httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
return httpResponse;
```

Now this is causing issues because the connections are never being closed. Using the using statement or a close in the callee will destroy the object before it's returned. The right way to do this would be something like.

```
using (httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse())
{
    return GetDataFromResponse(httpResp);
}
```

But unfortunately there are many calls into the helper class that are expecting the response object back and then serialize the data in the caller's own way.

I tried doing this on the calls into the helper.

```
using(HttpWebResponse httpResponseRecieved = WebHelper.MakeRequest(parameters))
```

but this doesn't seem to close the response. Is `httpResponseRecieved` a different object than the one returned? Is there a better solution or will I have to rewrite the method and all of its callers?

Comment: Your last `using` should be closing the response. What leads you to believe that it is not closed?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I had previously done some testing and it had appeared the error still persisted using the last `using` statement. I'm redoing those test now and it seems it is working as you stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohnSaunders pointed out, the last `using` that is wrapped around the caller is closing the response.

So doing `using(HttpWebResponse httpResponseRecieved = WebHelper.MakeRequest(parameters))` works after all.